# Is there something wrong with this php if statement?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is what I have included in the `head` of my WordPress site. However, it is producing a blank page. Is there something I might have overlooked?

```
<?php if (is_page('talent')) || (is_page('work')) { ?>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yes. Your **error log**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breakets are mismatching

```
if (is_page('talent') || (is_page('work'))){
```

try replacing your if statement with the given

and `echo` is missing before `bloginfo('template_url')`

Comment: No need for an echo there for bloginfo. If you use get_bloginfo then you need to use the echo. Thanks

Comment: thanks vasanthan.R.P ,I just confused for a while between bloginfo and get_bloginfo , now its clear

Answer (score 2):

The answers of both @chaitanyaMutyala and @Poonam are both right, but neither is complete. You need both fixes. The parenthesis don't match in your `if` statement and you need to `echo` the url:

```
<?php if (is_page('talent') || (is_page('work')) { ?>
    <script src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Poonam's answer seemed to work without using `echo`. Is using `echo` just a better way of writing it?

Comment: No, they are actually different. `echo` puts the result in html. Leaving it out puts nothing in the html. But I guess `bloginfo()` has the "echo" in it itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo bloginfo('template_url');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chek below code.

->if statement replace with this one:

`if (is_page('talent') || (is_page('work')) {`

-> src attribute in script tag replace with below one:

`echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js`